# knitr chunk in footnote with jekyll

Tags: r, jekyll, knitr, pandoc

In the [kramdown markdown documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#footnotes) I read that I can insert multi line footnotes by indenting the next lines in the footnote. I tried to insert a knitr chunk into the footnote like this:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
layout: post
---
My text[^1]

[^1]:This should appear in a footnote:
    ```{r}
    runif(1:10)
    ```
````

This worked when compiling the footnote directly with knitr:
[image: footnote generated by jekyll]

If I let jekyll compile it it looks differently:

[image]

The code chunk is not really in the footnote. It is above it. And it is indented like this is not properly recognized as footnote annotation.

In `config.yaml` I defined `markdown: kramdown`.

Answer (score 1):

Knitr uses [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) under the hood. To achieve the same output with Jekyll, you should use [jekyll-pandoc](https://github.com/mfenner/jekyll-pandoc), thus in `config.yaml` instead of `markdown: kramdown` then `markdown: pandoc`.

Comment: Good hint. I installed `jekyll-pandoc` and got it to work (see my answer). However it takes much longer to compile my posts than with knitr or with jekyll using kramdown... Actually annoyingly long.

Answer (score 1):

As @mb21 pointed out switching `markdown: kramdown` to `pandoc` makes jekyll use the same markdown compiler as knitr does by default. You have to install the `jekyll-pandoc` gem first. This is best done with bundler:

According to [bundler.io](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html), in a command line:

```
gem install bundler
cd /path/to/my/project
bundle init
```

According to [jekyll-pandoc](https://github.com/mfenner/jekyll-pandoc):

```
nano Gemfile
```

overwrite with the following:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "jekyll-pandoc"
```

save.

Then:

```
bundle install
```

This will install `jekyll-pandoc` and all dependencies.

In your project add this to your `_config.yaml`:

```
# Build settings
gems:
  - jekyll-pandoc
markdown: pandoc
```

(replace `markdown: kramdown`).

To generate your site use this command inside R:

```
servr::jekyll(command="bundle exec jekyll build")
```