# Include a chunk in an R Markdown footnote

Tags: r, r-markdown

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019756/knitr-chunk-in-footnote-with-jekyll) is the closest question I have found to mine, but it looks a bit dated.

I want to add a code chunk with `eval = FALSE` into the **footnote** of an R Markdown html document. I have tried the standard notation as in 2.5.1 [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/markdown-syntax.html), but knitting ignores it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if it your footnote looks like this:

````
Random Numbers[^a-random-footnote-label]

Other text for your document.

Other text for your document.

Other text for your document.

[^a-random-footnote-label]: 
    ```{r, echo = F}
    runif(1:10)
    ```
````

So you don't define the footnote directly via `Random Numbers^[content footnote]`. Instead you name it and define the contents later.